# run command with sudo su in script and redirect stdin and stdout

Tags: sudo, io-redirection, su, fifo

I need to run command as another user and write to its stdin and read from its stdout.
I can run command as another user only via opening new shell: `sudo su anotheruser` but with new opened shell i will lost stdin and stdout of caller. I am not allowed to run `sudo -u anotheruser -c command`

I found out that i can use named pipes for stdin/stdout redirection, so i wrote a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkfifo pipein
mkfifo pipeout

echo '/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server 0<pipein >pipeout' | sudo su anotheruser

cat 0<&1 >pipein & cat <pipeout

wait
```

But it doesn't work as desired. I want to redirect script's stdin to command's stdin and also redirect command's stdout to script's stdout - so i could seamlessly use the script as original command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have some editing errors in your post. There is a "&" missing for the sudo line, and you are using different names for your pipes later in the script.  Here is something that works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mkfifo pipein
mkfifo pipeout
echo '/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server <pipein >pipeout' | sudo su anotheruser &
cat <pipeout &
cat >pipein
wait
rm -f pipein pipeout
```

Comment: works great with little tweak: mkfifo pipeout --mode=0777, depends on relation between user running script and anotheruser

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely but I think you are after something like this:

```
sudo -u $USER sh -c "ls -la /home" | grep $USER
```

Or if you want the pipe as the other user

```
sudo -u $USER sh -c "ls -la /home | grep $USER"
```

Comment: i can't use sudo -u -c, i am allowed only to run "sudo su anotherdeveloper"